# A mathematical riddle

Tags: riddle, mathematics

> Three letters can define me,
> Sometimes even just one.
> Try to derive the answer,
> And you'll find just me.
>
> I'm so fast,
> I'm so slow,
> Up or down
> I will go.
>
> Some are based on different things,
> Though all but I are unnatural.
> My other may be found in woods,
> Now what am I, in truth?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You are

> the exponential function.

```
Three letters can define me,
```

> exp

```
Sometimes even just one.
```

> $e^{\dots}$

```
Try to derive the answer,
And you'll find just me.
```

> $\frac d{dx}\exp x=\exp x$

```
I'm so fast,
I'm so slow,
Up or down
I will go.
```

> I guess this is referring to exponential growth (something that increases like $\exp t$ soon finds itself increasing very, very fast) and exponential convergence (some other things look more like $1-\exp(-t)$ and after a while they change only very slowly).

```
Some are based on different things,
Though all but I are unnatural.
My other may be found in woods,
```

> The "other" is of course log, and logs are found in woods. Logarithms can be taken to different bases; those to base $e$ (the inverse of the exponential function) are called "natural logs", though I don't recall seeing that terminology in the context of exp itself.

```
Now what am I, in truth?
```

> You are still the exponential function. If there is some further cleverness behind the words "in truth", I haven't spotted it.

Comment: GAH I WAS JUST GOING TO WRITE "ROOT" as the answer Good Job +1

Comment: Correct! And I'm entirely unsurprised that it was you who solved it :-) Looks like you got all the clues (nope, no real riddlish content in the last line).

Comment: **Q:** Why shouldn't you do calculus while under the influence? **A:** Don't drink and derive.

Comment: @rand haha okok enough with these kinds of jokes

Answer (score 10):

**Partial Answer**

> A Logarithm or a Natural Logarithm

Three letters can define me,
Sometimes even just one.

> I know it can be "log" for three letters "ln" and "e" .

Try to derive the answer,
And you'll find just me.

> I am not sure on this one.

I'm so fast,
I'm so slow,
Up or down
I will go.

> I think this might have to due with a graph.

Some are based on different things,
Though all but I are unnatural.

> There are regular logarithms and natural logarithms.

My other may be found in woods,
Now what am I, in truth?

> Does this have to do with a log as in a tree log?

Comment: Check out Gareth's answer! :D

Comment: Yeah it's awesome! :D

Comment: Very very close. Gareth's answer is the right one, but you definitely deserve an upvote.

Answer (score 8):

### Partial Solution

Is the answer

> Ten?

Three letters can define me,

> T-E-N?

Sometimes even just one.

> Uh I'm not sure but is X ten in Roman Numerals?

Try to derive the answer,

> Derive an algebraic equation.

And you'll find just me.

> End up with just $x = ?$ which is what you want? $X$ appears again?

I'm so fast, I'm so slow,

> Not sure about this.

Up or down I will go.

> Not sure about this either.

Some are based on different things,

> Numbers can be base 9, base 11, base 2, etc.

Though all but I are unnatural.

> Only base 10 is natural to us?

My other may be found in woods,

> A TEN-T can be found in woods?

Now what am I, in truth?

> Then is 1 and 0 and these are booleans: true or false in coding?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Close? Not close? Atrociously off?

Comment: Not close, but another nice try. I like how you made it fit both the three-letter and one-letter parts. Unfortunately the second verse doesn't fit so well.

Answer (score 5):

> Sine, cosine, or tangent?

Three letters can define me,

> sin, cos, or tan is used

Sometimes even just one

> s, c, or t?

Try to derive the answer,

And you'll find just me.

> sine, cosine, and tan are derived from triangles

---

I'm so fast,

> They are used for equations with wavelengths of light which is fast

I'm so slow,

> of they can be used in equations representing much slower occurrences, such as tides

Up or down

I will go.

> The shape of a sine or cosine graph goes up and down

---

Some are based on different things,

> other stuff is defined in other ways

Though all but I are unnatural.

> they are used in many models of natural events

My other may be found in woods,

> unsure of this

Now what am I, in truth?

> Sine, cosine, or tangent

Comment: Nope, but good try.